# Django Footer and header on each page with {% extends }

Tags: html, css, django

So I'm trying to add the footer and header on every page of my website. I made a base.html file which contains the general layout of the site.

In my about.html page, i did:

```
{% extends "public/base.html" %}

<h1>Content goes here</h1>
```

I can see my header and footer, but how do I display the content. I want to type stuff in that about.html page. The content goes here isn't being displayed in the middle.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to define a block in base.html and populate it in about.html.

base.html:

```
<header>...</header>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
<footer>...</footer>
```

about.html

```
{% extends "public/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Content goes here</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

This is all fully explained in the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks! I added the block content and endblock and it worked!

Comment: Quickk question. So what if i wanted to edit the text and layout with css, would i make a seperate css file just for that page and how would I extend that? Same way?

Comment: So CSS is considered a static file, so you would use: `{% load staticfiles %}`. More here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/ Also, mark the answer as correct if it is.

Comment: I just went through the 7 part tutorial and while the block content aspect is explained, the use of `{% extends "public/base.html" %}` is not. Nonetheless a easy to understand answer so thanks!

Comment: i could not find this in the Django official tutorial.. please link if possible..

Comment: i added those two files to my project, and nothing changed

Answer (score 12):

```
{% extends "public/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Content goes here</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Or simply create `about.html` and include it where you want in your main html.

Example:

```
    {% extends "public/base.html" %}
    {% block content %}
       "Your code"
    {% include "core/about.html" %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I definitely prefer yours, for it allows to distinguish easily the footer in non authenticated mode from the header in the other cases

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your base.html looks like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- header code -->
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
        <!-- footer code -->
    </body>
<html>
```

Then in your other file you would do this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <!-- Content here -->
{% endblock %}
```

Anything placed inside the template's (extended file's) body tag would be overwritten by the stuff in the child file's content, but anything outside of that tag would be extended, or copied, into it.

Here are [the docs on the block tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#template-inheritance)

Comment: The block name should be the case in the parent and extended templates. In this case, in the other file, the block should start with `{% block content %}`, not `{% block body %}`.

Comment: Right you are. Edited.